# Music drowning out singing

Tags: levels, post-production

my brother gave me some raw footage of him playing the guitar. His mouth was not close enough to the mic and the guitar sounds too loud. Is there a way I can remove increase the voice or lower the guitar. The only editing software I have is Audacity and Sony movie studio. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If it was recorded with one microphone, there is no good way to rectify this problem.

Vocals and guitars share the same frequencies, so EQ is out of the picture.

Sorry.